# Check if date crash with another

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two variables: start_time, end_time, which I need to compare with two other identical variables to see if they collide. Is there a function I can use?

Comment: `start_time1 == start_time2 and end_time1 == end_time2`? But probably I do not fully understand what  is happening. It might help if you show an example with sample input and (expected) output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the 2 time ranges overlap each other. In that case, here is the one liner

```
is_overlap = not (end_time1 < start_time2 or end_time2 < start_time1)
```